# web page is not filtering items in selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, dictionary, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to scrap data from a web page. But the problem is, when i am using the following code it's not filtering the results. The page is showing 120 items. but after i send_key and click(), it should return 73 items and then i should retrieve those 73 data. Does anyone know how to fix this? TIA

```
driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value='//*[@id="locationSearch"]').send_keys('Ontario, CA')
time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value='/html/body/div/div/div[3]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/ul/li[1]').click()
time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value='//*[@id="app"]/div[3]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/button').click()
time.sleep(5)

getListingUrls = driver.find_elements(
by=By.XPATH, value='//*[@id="catalog-listing"]/article/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/h2/a')
```

Comment: It's hard to find the problem without page source. Please provide either url if it's public, or DOM

Comment: https://www.unitedrentals.com/marketplace/equipment/aerial-work-platforms  
filter this page by setting the location to "Ontario, CA"

Comment: you should put all information in question, not in comments. This way more people can see it and more people can help you.

Comment: sometime page needs longer `sleep()`

Comment: it would be simpler if you would create `minimal working code` which we could copy and run - and we could use it to create answer.

Comment: it seems your code doesn't click button `Set location`. You also doesn't use `send_keys` to send `Enter` which could works instead of `Set location`

Comment: This page use `CloudFlare` and sometimes it can't get results because `CloudFlare` try to check if it is not a script and it send response with error 503 instead of filtered data.

Comment: if I run with standard Chrome driver then `CloudFlare` blocks filtered results - but it works when I use [undetected-chromedriver](https://github.com/ultrafunkamsterdam/undetected-chromedriver)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`import undetected_chromedriver as uc`
`driver = uc.Chrome()`

Thanks @furas https://stackoverflow.com/users/1832058/furas